# JavaScript contracts and assertions

Tags: javascript, assert, design-by-contract

This has bugged me for a while. I throw an exception on an assertion failure, but this is only helpful if I can actually catch the exception (in which case I `alert` the user). If I can't catch the exception, then

1. I'm relying on the browser to notify the user that there's been an internal error (the browser may do nothing, so the user never finds out that there's a problem), and
2. I don't get a look-in, and so can't clean up.

So, is there actually a good way to handle assertion errors in JavaScript? Is there some way to catch uncaught exceptions? Note that I'm not interested in unit testing, user errors, and so on - I'm only concerned with contract programming, where both the user and developer need to know that there has been an error.

Answer (score 2):

For assertions, there is [`console.assert()`](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.assert.28expression.5B.2C_object.2C_....5D.29). But that will only log the message and go on.

With HTML5 it is also possible to catch unhandled exceptions using the [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror) handler. There's an [excellent article on dev.opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/) how this can be used to show fancy error messages to the user and even log exceptions to the server.

If you can't use that, you're left with wrapping try-catch-clauses around everything (especially "execution entry points" like event handlers, timeouts and co.). Or you could handle the errors before throwing them:

```
function SmartError(message) {
    Error.call(this, message);
    $('<div class="error">Some problem occured, the app will stop working</div>')
        .appendTo("body");
    $.post("/log/clientside/js.php", this);
    ...
}

if (something.does(! "work"))
    throw new SmartError("mysterious problem");
```

Comment: The prpblem often is, browsers that are smart enough for `onerror`, don't throw the annoying, tricky errors =) Definitely good answer though!